# KeyError: 'commentCount' using Youtube API in Python

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use this python code to get data from Youtube API v3.

First there's a function built to get view count, like counts, dislike counts and comment counts, then there's another big block that's itself a function to get infos like 'video id' and finally it puts everything in a pandas dataframe.

It works fine with some YouTube channels except that with some other channels it fails to get the number of comments. I hit this error message in my Python Notebook :

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-46-de3cf6032d33> in <module>()
      5 df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['video_id','video_title','upload_date','view_count','like_count','dislike_count','comment_count'])
      6 
----> 7 df2 = get_videos(df2)

1 frames

<ipython-input-44-90ae6e5b0155> in get_video_details(video_id)
      8     like_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']
      9     dislike_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['dislikeCount']
---> 10     comment_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount']
     11 
     12     #return view_count

KeyError: 'commentCount'
```

I imagine a `if else` statement could do the trick but wouldn't be the best option anyway.

Here's the code in full :

```
# Import libraries
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

# Keys
API_KEY = 'xxx'
CHANNEL_ID = 'xxx'

def get_video_details(video_id):

    #collecting view, like, dislike, comment counts
    url_video_stats = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+video_id+'&part=statistics&key='+API_KEY
    response_video_stats = requests.get(url_video_stats).json()

    view_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']
    like_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']
    dislike_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['dislikeCount']
    comment_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount']

    return view_count, like_count, dislike_count, comment_count

def get_videos(df):
    pageToken = ''
    while 1:
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='+API_KEY+'&channelId='+CHANNEL_ID+'&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=10000&'+pageToken

        response = requests.get(url).json()
        time.sleep(1) #give it a second before starting the for loop
        for video in response['items']:
            if video['id']['kind'] == "youtube#video":
                video_id = video['id']['videoId']
                video_title = video['snippet']['title']
                video_title = str(video_title).replace('&amp;','')
                upload_date = video['snippet']['publishedAt']
                upload_date = str(upload_date).split("T")[0]
                #view_count = get_video_details(video_id)
                view_count, like_count, dislike_count, comment_count = get_video_details(video_id)

                df = df.append({'video_id':video_id,
                                'video_title':video_title,
                                'upload_date':upload_date,
                                'view_count':view_count,
                                'like_count':like_count,
                                'dislike_count':dislike_count,
                                'comment_count':comment_count},
                               ignore_index=True)
        try:
            if response['nextPageToken'] != None: #if none, it means it reached the last page and break out of it
                pageToken = 'pageToken=' + response['nextPageToken']

        except:
            break


    return df

#build our dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['video_id','video_title','upload_date','view_count','like_count','dislike_count','comment_count']) 

df2 = get_videos(df2)
```

Comment: `.get('commentCount', 0)` ?

Comment: I put that in a Try Except and that does the trick

Answer (score 0):

A `try except` in the first function does solve the problem fine

```
def get_video_details(video_id):

    #collecting view, like, dislike, comment counts
    url_video_stats = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+video_id+'&part=statistics&key='+API_KEY
    response_video_stats = requests.get(url_video_stats).json()

    #view_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']
    #like_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']
    #dislike_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['dislikeCount']
    #comment_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount']

    view_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']
    try:
      like_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']
    except KeyError:
      like_count = response_video_stats.get('likeCount', 0)
    try:
      dislike_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['dislikeCount']
    except:
      dislike_count = response_video_stats.get('dislikeCount', 0)
    try:
      comment_count = response_video_stats['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount']
    except:
      comment_count = response_video_stats.get('commentCount', 0)

    return view_count, like_count, dislike_count, comment_count
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but I had the same issue and went with if-else statements.  I am particularly interested if comment sections are nonexistent anyway, since that could suggest that they were disabled by the channel owner.

```
    comments = []
    for key in data['items']:
        if 'commentCount' in key['statistics']:
            comment_count = key['statistics']['commentCount']
            comments.append(comment_count)
        else:
            comments.append(0)
```